# mysql query select two columns each from two different set of tables

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

Need to select two columns each from two different set of tables.

Right now I have this as two different queries but wanted to know if there is a way to have this in one single query

**Query-1**

```
 SELECT     
        BSM, DATE, HOUR, SUM(t.ATT), SUM(t.AVG_HLD)
    FROM (
        SELECT BSM, DATE, HOUR, ATT, AVG_HLD FROM t1 WHERE  ".$whereCondition." UNION ALL
        SELECT BSM, DATE, HOUR, ATT, AVG_HLD FROM t2 WHERE  ".$whereCondition." 
        ) t
    GROUP BY BSM, DATE, HOUR ";
```

**Query-2**

```
 SELECT     
        BSM, DATE, HOUR, SUM(s.M_ATT), SUM(s.M_AVG_HLD)
    FROM (
        SELECT BSM, DATE, HOUR, M_ATT, AVG_HLD FROM t3 WHERE    ".$whereCondition." UNION ALL
        SELECT BSM, DATE, HOUR, M_ATT, AVG_HLD FROM t4 WHERE    ".$whereCondition."
        ) s
    GROUP BY BSM, DATE, HOUR ";
```

**How to combine both Query-1 and Query-2 like...**

```
 SELECT     
        BSM, DATE, HOUR, SUM(s.ATT), SUM(s.AVG_HLD), SUM(s.M_ATT), SUM(s.M_AVG_HLD)
    FROM (
        ** Whatever it is **
        ) 
    GROUP BY BSM, DATE, HOUR ";
```

Comment: For simplicity, I'd remove the php bit for now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a `UNION` of all 4 subqueries, inserting `0` columns for the columns that come from the other pair of tables.

```
SELECT BSM, DATE, HOUR, SUM(ATT) AS ATT, SUM(AVG_HLD) AS AVG_HLD, SUM(M_ATT) AS M_ATT, SUM(M_AVG_HLD) AS M_AVG_HLD
FROM (
        SELECT BSM, DATE, HOUR, ATT, AVG_HLD, 0 AS M_ATT, 0 AS M_AVG_HLD FROM t1 WHERE  ".$whereCondition." 
        UNION ALL
        SELECT BSM, DATE, HOUR, ATT, AVG_HLD, 0 AS M_ATT, 0 AS M_AVG_HLD FROM t2 WHERE  ".$whereCondition." 
        UNION ALL
        SELECT BSM, DATE, HOUR, 0 AS ATT, 0 AS AVG_HLD, M_ATT, M_AVG_HLD FROM t3 WHERE    ".$whereCondition." 
        UNION ALL
        SELECT BSM, DATE, HOUR, 0 AS ATT, 0 AS AVG_HLD, M_ATT, M_AVG_HLD FROM t4 WHERE    ".$whereCondition."
    ) u
GROUP BY BSM, DATE, HOUR
```

Comment: thanks Barmar. But guess the column order should be same across subquires. otherwise im getting 0 value for M_ATT column. Am i correct?

Comment: how do i uniquely refer the ATT columns from t1 and t2 separately? something like this `SELECT BSM, DATE, HOUR, SUM(t1.ATT) AS t1ATT, SUM(t2.ATT) AS t2.ATT...`

Comment: You need to add new columns to the `SELECT` clauses of the subqueries, e.g. `SELECT ..., ATT, ATT AS t1ATT, 0 AS t2ATT ... FROM t1 ... UNION SELECT ..., ATT, 0 AS t1ATT, ATT AS t2ATT ... FROM t2`. Then the outer query can use `SUM(t1ATT), SUM(t2ATT), ...`

Answer (score 1):

You can also try it this way

```
SELECT bsm, date, hour, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN src = 1 THEN att END) att, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN src = 1 THEN att_hld END) att_hld, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN src = 2 THEN att END) m_att, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN src = 2 THEN att_hld END) m_att_hld
FROM 
(
    SELECT 1 src, bsm, date, hour, att, avg_hld FROM t1 WHERE  ".$whereCondition." UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 src, bsm, date, hour, att, avg_hld FROM t2 WHERE  ".$whereCondition." UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 src, bsm, date, hour, m_att, avg_hld FROM t3 WHERE ".$whereCondition." UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 src, bsm, date, hour, m_att, avg_hld FROM t4 WHERE ".$whereCondition."
) t
 GROUP BY bsm, date, hour;
```

Comment: Can i rewrite this `SUM(CASE WHEN src = 1 THEN att END) att` as `ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN src = 1 THEN att+att_hld*100 END) ,2) att` ???